# Should elements of RDF triple always be URI?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web

Is it possible to use URI for the subject, predicate and object in RDF or should there be a keyword in at least one of the triple, example:

```
David <http://www.someuri.com/predicate> <http://www.someuri.com/object>
```

Is it possible to have this kind of structure in an RDF file or should all the triples be in URI form?

For example if i have a doctor called David, patient and date of visit are in form of URI. Let the patient URI be "http://www.hospital.com/patients/" and the date URI be "http://www.hospital.com/dateofvisit/". In this case can you please tell me how the RDF document should be created.

Answer (score 9):

Subject is either a URI or a blank node.

Predicate is always a URI.

Object is either a URI, a blank node or a literal.

`David` is not a valid URI nor a blank node identifier in any common RDF syntax. You probably want to model it as a URI resource. It doesn't have to be an HTTP URL however, any valid URI will do.

Comment: Presumably, this David is a human being composed of blood bone and personality, and not the letters D a v i and d, therefore its right, in a sense, to model the name as a property of an abstract entity and represent the abstract entity, per convention, with a URL (to allow for node folding)

Answer (score 2):

Sreenath, In RDF the parts of a triple can be either IRIs (Unicode compatible URIs), literals (strings, integers etc) or 'blank nodes' (a kind of anonymous URLs for temporary references). Your 'keyword' sounds like a shortened form of an IRI - if you define a default prefix for your RDF document, then the keyword should be considered relative to that. If the node is enclosed in quotes, then it is a literal. The only other option is that your triple component is a blank node, which is also a resource locator, but only relative to this document. It would look like this `_:David` You can find out more [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/#structuredproperties)